# Ogre3D installation with GCC, C::B in Win8

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, ogre3d

I'm trying to set up a Ogre3D v1.8.1 with Code Blocks 12.11 which has GCC 4.7.0 configured in it. I downloaded the pre compiled version of Ogre3D for MinGW, start up example compiles and executes program without error, but during the initialization of Ogre3D(driver selection screen) some errors occurs and apps freezes. Deliberate search on net revealed that there are so many post on internet where many people has stuck on that stage of program that couldn't pass.

C::B compiler report after Ogre3D scrren crashes

```
 In __cxa_throw () (D:\Ogre3D_181\OgreSDK_MinGW_v1-8-1\bin\Debug\OgreMain_d.dll)
 87 ..\..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreConfigFile.cpp: No such file or directory.
 #1  0x009507e9 in Ogre::ConfigFile::loadDirect (this=0x28fc48, filename=...,
 separators=..., trimWhitespace=true) at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreConfigFile.cpp:87
 Debugger finished with status 0
```

Ogre3D.log report is as shown below

```
 13:19:34: MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardSet' registered.
 13:19:34: MovableObjectFactory for type 'ManualObject' registered.
 13:19:34: MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardChain' registered.
 13:19:34: MovableObjectFactory for type 'RibbonTrail' registered.
 13:19:34: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): 'plugins.cfg' file not found! in     
 ConfigFile::load at ..\..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreConfigFile.cpp (line 88)
```

Based on the complaints produced by Ogre3D and C::B, It may seem that I'm not passing the correct include/source/lib directories and external dependencies correctly but actually I've followed instructions from official Ogre3D site and I'm sure that this is correct because otherwise compiler should have thrown the exception during the compilation. Along with that other users also experienced such kind of problems even though they configure the enviroment properly.

Another Error

```
  07:09:37: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Unable to compile Cg program      
  Ogre/DualQuaternionHardwareSkinningTwoWeightsTwoPhaseCg: The compile returned an    
  error.DualQuaternion_Common.cg(167) : warning C7019: "blendWgt" is too large for  
   semantic    
  "BLENDWEIGHT", which is size 1
   (0) : error C6007: Constant register limit exceeded; more than 96 constant registers   
   needed to compiled program

   (0) : error C6007: Constant register limit exceeded; more than 96 constant registers   
   needed to compiled program
   (0) : error C6007: Constant register limit exceeded; more than 96 constant registers 
   needed to compiled program
    in CgProgram::compileMicrocode at 
   ..\..\..\..\..\..\PlugIns\CgProgramManager\src\OgreCgProgramManagerDll.cpp (line 67)
```

Your guidance will be appreicated,

Comment: Can you please post the complete `Ogre.log` log file.

Comment: Here is the full Ogre.log https://www.dropbox.com/s/6eega7mb38h1evb/Ogre.log

Answer (score 2):

The exception is not complaining about source directories or external dependencies. It's complaining about missing `plugins.cfg` file. The most relevant line in the log is this:

> OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): 'plugins.cfg' file not found! in...

The location of that file is passed to the constructor of [Root](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/classOgre_1_1Root.html). The demos probably use the root of [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). Make sure that the working directory is set correctly and the file is in that path.

See this guide [Setting Up An Application - CodeBlocks](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Setting+Up+An+Application+-+CodeBlocks)

> If you want to run your executable from within Code::Blocks, you need to set up 'working directory' and 'command' in the project settings like this: (see the image from that page)

You can find more basic info about initialization and what plugins.cfg is in this [tutorial](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Basic+Ogre+Application)

Comment: When I surpass one error, then another emerges this time it is 'OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): I added the output to the main message ' I don't think that its related with code malfuntioning or syntax, most probably it is the plugins configuration files what causes discrepancy, they come with full set of plugins which is not required I believe. One thing that confuses me is that Ogre console screen and C::B compiler reports are not reporting the same error if there is any exception, is that how its expected to be ?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your second error:

As the message clearly states, your Cg program tries to use more registers than are available on your machine. This depends on the graphics cards (which one are you using)?

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you might have to adjust the shaders a bit so that they stay within in the supported bounds of your hardware.

See for example this [Ogre3D forums thread](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=487729#p487729) where something similar happened with the *DualQuaternion* shader and the user just reduced the bone count. On ATI cards, usually only 24 bones are supported in that shader.

*On important note:* Many issues in that area have been fixed with Ogre v1.9, so I would advise you to update if possible. v1.9 has been stable since quite some time (in fact we are already preparing the next release v.1.0).

Comment: Thank you, after commenting out some of the plugins especially the CGxxx. in plugins.cfg file I managed to get the ogre head in console screen. AFAIU In my case they unnecessarily been loaded just because they ship with default configuration. It's good to hear that 1.9 is more stable and easy to install.